# Unable to browse layerlists in GeoServer using HTTPS

Tags: geoserver, http

The problem is I have numerous layers in GeoServer and the layer list extends to at four three pages.  I am unable to move from page 1 to view other layers by using the numbered pages or the arrow buttons at the foot of the layer list.  I am also unable to use the search function above the layer.  The same thing occurs with data stores.

I am running GeoServer 2.23 on Debian/Tomcat through HTTPS.

If I switch to HTTP (and include port number).  I.e change from HTTPS://my.domain.net/geoserver to HTTP://my.domain.net:8080/geoserver  then the problem does not occur and Geoserver behaves normally.

I would like to close off the insecure HTTP option.  Has anyone else experienced this problem or know of a solution?

Comment: Did you set the proxy URL under global settings?

Comment: Yes the Proxy base URL is set to "https ://my.domain.net" (as per examples above) *without the space

Comment: What is the error message? Could be xsfr orcors?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should be `https://my.domain.net/geoserver`

Comment: The error is bad request 400 type:xhr.  I have tried changing proxy base URL to  https://my.domain.net/geoserver, with no change.

Comment: this one https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/webadmin/csrf.html